# Apache Query String Rewrite

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite a query string in Apache.

**The current (example) domain is:**
example.com/?domain=domain.com

**I would like this to then be rewritten into:**
example.com/domain.com

**So, when a user enters:**
example.com/?domain=domain.com

**They are always redirected to the pretty version:**
example.com/domain.com

I've tried quite a few different rewrites, such as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?domain=$1 [L]
```

But this fails to work (i.e. nothing happens) with .htaccess and ModRewrite enabled.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^domain=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/%1? [L]
```

Empty question mark at the end is important as it will discard the original query string.